# Why does FixAntenna not include tag 371 in a Reject message?

Tags: c#, fix-protocol

After loading an order I receive an execution report back, which is then rejected by my fix engine - FixAntenna of Epam Systems/B2BITS.

The reason is showed as tag specified without a value. :   373 = 4

Now some tags of price and qty are zero - but I can't for sure figure out easily which tag is the culprit as FixAntenna does not include Tag 371 in the reject message. While Tag 371 is not a required tag, it would indicate to me the tag in question that is causing the reject.  Any ideas?  Using Fix 4.2

The epam dictionary link for reference [here](https://btobits.com/fixopaedia/fixdic42/index.html?tag_20_ExecTransType.html)

Exection report FIX message:

```
20230814 16:52:29.953870000 - 8=FIX.4.2�9=330�35=8�115=SAS�34=4�49=IR�52=20230814-14:52:29.944�56=RID�1=LCE1�6=0.000000�11=stringOnlyID�14=0�15=ZAR�17=36�20=0�21=1�22=8�31=0.000000�32=0�37=22�38=1�39=A�40=2�44=3150�48=Instr�54=1�55=Instr�59=0�60=20230814-14:52:29.944�150=A�151=1�167=FUT�198=69337265�200=202312�205=20�207=APD�424=1�425=0�426=0.000000�10=223�
```

Answer (score 0):

`373=4` means `TAG_SPECIFIED_WITHOUT_A_VALUE`, so that should be easy to spot. Just search for `=` immediately followed by ASCII code 1 (the end-of-field delimiter).

Comment: There is no tag without a value... that is what is confusing.

Comment: If all the tags have values, then `SessionRejectReason` (tag 373) has an incorrect value. I suggest you report this bug to the trading venue's support team. Hopefully they will: (1) be able to tell you the real problem with your troublesome message, and also (2) fix the bug in their system (the incorrect value for `SessionRejectReason`).

Comment: I have contacted them - would you suggest going into source code and checking?  A tall order for a novice / intermediate coder?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you and  thought that it was the trading venue that was rejecting your message. Now I see it is actually your FIX engine (FixAntenna) that is rejecting an ExecutionReport message received from the trading venue. If you haven't already done so, I suggest you contact FixAntenna's support team to see if they can help. If you have access to the source code of FixAntenna, then, yes, examining the source code and possibly using some breakpoints in a debugger might help you to analyze the problem.